# Oracle PL/SQL-Moving duplicate rows into 1 row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have the following rows in a table. in this case columns atr can be used for any other purpose hence i want to move this 3 rows into one row, moving each unique sup_name to either of the atr columns.

I want to move the column sup_name entries to its respective individual columns in order to avoid redundancy.

```
CREATE TABLE dups
( dups_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  dups_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
sup_name varchar2(50)
  atr1 varchar2(50)
 atr2 varchar2(50)
 atr3 varchar2(50)
 atr4 varchar2(50)
);

    insert into dups(dups_id,dups_name,sup_name,atr1,atr2,atr3)
 values(1,'Resego Kebopetswe', 'resego231dty',null,null,null)
    insert into dups(dups_id,dups_name,sup_name,atr1,atr2,atr3)
 values(2,'Resego Kebopetswe', 'resego532dty',null,null,null)
    insert into dups(dups_id,dups_name,sup_name,atr1,atr2,atr3)
 values(3,'Resego Kebopetswe', 'resego420qas',null,null,null)

dups_id   dups_name          sup_name      atr1   atr2   atr3    
1         Resego Kebopetswe  resego231dty  null   null   null    
2         Resego Kebopetswe  resego532dty  null   null   null    
3         Resego Kebopetswe  resego420qas  null   null   null
```

i want it to end up as below

```
dups_id   dups_name          sup_name      atr1          atr2          atr3    
1         Resego Kebopetswe  resego231dty  resego532dty  resego420qas  null
```

Comment: not really i do not want to altogether remove rows but i want to insure i merge the given sup_name to its respective dups_name

Comment: Ok, Show us the expected result in tabular format.

Comment: i just did that

Comment: What happens if there are 4 entries per dups_name or 2 ?

Comment: i just want each sup_name to be be moved to a different column. That is 1 dups_name can have many sup_name

Comment: Do you want that merging to happen automatically when you run an INSERT? Or are you simply looking for a statement that changes the table and merges those rows together

Comment: i want thestatement that changes the table and merge the rows together

Answer (score 0):

This pivot query shows sup_names for duplicated name in `atr1`...`atr4` columns.

```
select sup_name_id dups_id, dups_name, sup_name, atr1, atr2, atr3, atr4
  from (select dups_id, dups_name, sup_name, 
               row_number() over (partition by dups_name order by dups_id) rn 
          from dups d)
  pivot(min(dups_id) id, max(sup_name) for rn in (1 sup_name, 2 atr1, 3 atr2, 4 atr3, 5 atr4))
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f5503c09001d16eec5eaf9e15bf24050)</sup>**

```
DUPS_ID DUPS_NAME           SUP_NAME      ATR1          ATR2          ATR3     ATR4
------- ------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  -------  --------
      1 Resego Kebopetswe   resego231dty  resego532dty  resego420qas
```

If you want to update values in your table then use this query in `merge` as source data.